# How to transform a ByteArrayOutputStream in order to loop using readline

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I want to download a file using FTP, and then keep the file in memory and simply loop over the lines.

I am downloading the file like this so far:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
ftp.retrieveFile("inventory.csv", bos)
```

I'm not sure how to go from a ByteArrayOutputStream to be able to loop each line.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)

Comment: how are you parsing the csv?

Comment: It makes more sense to parse it first with something like opencsv and hold in memory the parsed columns. Otherwise you would be reprising over and over

Comment: @efekctive haven't gotten to that stage, just downloading from the remote ftp server first.  Just might do a simple string split b/c the csv is very simple and maybe only 5-6 columns.

Comment: then you need to call ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray turn this into an String(byte[]) and process in loop. Make sure you ignore the cvs header line (if it has one). If his works let me know I will post it as an answer. EDIT: You would need and stringreader too

Comment: @efekctive . Yes that sounds like it will work.  There is no header in the csv.

Comment: answer posted. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is the idea I had in mind, save minor overlooks, it should help you:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
FTPClient   ftp;
String line;
ArrayList<String[]> values;
try{
    bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ftp = new FTPClient();
    if (ftp.retrieveFile("inventory.csv", bos)){
        values = new ArrayList<>();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(new String(bos.toByteArray())));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            values.add(line.split(","));
        }
        // Then you could switch ArrayList<String[]> for just String[] 
    }

}
catch(Exception x){

}
finally{
    if (bufferedReader != null)
        bufferedReader.close();
    if (bos != null)
        bos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `retrieveFileStream()` instead and then read line by line in a try-with-resources block using a `BufferedReader`.

```
try (BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(ftp.retrieveFileStream("inventory.csv"),
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // do something with line
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

The code assumes that the file is encoded in UTF-8. If a different encoding is used make sure to replace `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` accordingly.

The advantage over an intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream` is that at no point your program needs to have a copy of the whole file content in memory.